# How to use git difftool inside a Jenkins job?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, difftool

I'm using git to manage configuration revisions.

I would like to run difftool during jenkins job to allow the user to decide which line is correct during the job. is there any plugin that can do this?

example: ( file was changed in workspace and user should be able to modify as he needs )

```
chen@DEV-Chen:/tmp/configuration_repo$ git status 
On branch env.env68
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/env.env68'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working 
directory)

    modified:   env.env68/backend.properties

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
chen@DEV-Chen:/tmp/configuration_repo$ git difftool -y .
```

[image: meld running using git difftool]

Comment: Isn't the whole point of Jenkins to build automatically, without human intervention?

Comment: why would you do this in Jenkins? Jenkins is just a deployment pipeline. Merged should be done by a developer once he merges it into ReleaseCandidate

Comment: The question is about difftool but actually its a general question about how to interact with the build process. there is a "remote terminal access plugin" but i follow the docs and i cant make it work. any help would be appreciated.